# How to restore multiple explorer windows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am doing some work in a database application, entering some data, and then scanning relevant information to PDF that I must then copy to a remote location.

I have two Windows Explorer windows tiled side-by-side of the scanned location and the remote location.  When I'm done with my scanning I'd like to be able to restore both of the Explorer windows at once but can't seem to do it without clicking twice.

Is there a way to restore the window position of all the Explorer windows in the group?

I've found that ctrl-clicking will restore successive windows in the group, but I'd like a single action if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Shift right-click should let you work with the entire group of windows.  A nice collection of tips like that can be found here:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1511-mastering-window-management-with-windows-7-tricks/

Comment: I tried this and found it slightly more cumbersome than I'd like. Using this I need to hunt down the side-by-side entry in the list instead of ctrl-clicking twice on the group (only two in the group so it works)